# I'm having an issue populating a select input with information from state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select

> setting state to an empty object

`const [categories, setCategories] = useState({});`

> making an axios call and setting state. I checked and res returns correct data.

```
  const res = await axios.get(`${API}/categories`);
  setCategories(res.data);
};


useEffect(() => {
  getCategories()
},[])
```

> creating form and trying to populate select bar

```
      <h1>Add New Item</h1>
      <section className="form">
        <form>
         
          <label htmlFor="category">Category: </label>

          <select id="category" required>
            <option disabled selected value>
              Select A Category
            </option>

            {Object.keys(categories).map((category) => (
              <option value={category.category_id}>{category.name}</option>
            ))} {console.log(categories)}
          </select>

   
        </form>
      </section>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: can you please display the response which comes from API call (const res = await axios.get(`${API}/categories`))

Comment: What is the issue? Please provide more detail and context for the issue you have and what you are asking of anyone here to help you with. Also, don't console log in the render as an unintentional side-effect, it's unreliable for making any sort of assertion on.

Answer (score 0):

**Code Solution**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6twagp?file=src/App.js

I tried solving this

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState();
  const API = 'https://fakestoreapi.com/';
  const getCategories = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API}/products`);
    setCategories(res.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add New Item</h1>
      <section className="form">
        <form>
          <label htmlFor="category">Category: </label>

          <select id="category" required>
            <option disabled selected value>
              Select A Category
            </option>
            {categories &&
              categories.map((category) => (
                <option value={category.id}>{category.title}</option>
              ))}
          </select>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```